# How to deal with a link in an email sent to a user that leads to a page with private user-specific data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a link in all sent emails that leads users to a page that allows them to edit their email settings. However, if the user is not logged in when he or she clicks on the link, an error is thrown (since the email settings are pulled through the association with `current_user`).

I'd like to instead show the login page if the user is not currently signed in, and upon signing in, they are redirected to the email settings page. What is a good way of setting up this logic? I'm using Ruby on Rails and Devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the edit action in email_settings controller is called, add the `authenticate_user!` helper from devise as a before filter.

```
class EmailSettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update] 

    def edit
      //logic to pull current user email settings
    end

end
```

Devise will take care of redirecting the user to the login page and on successful login, take the user back to the email settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the unauthenticated user to the login url, an additional parameter that will hold the URL to the email changing page (the URL that is sent in the email)